# Authentication and authorization issue in Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 over SSL only in a Java project

Tags: spring, ssl, activemq-classic

I am trying to configure Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 over SSL only and test for authentication and authorization on Windows7. In activemq.xml file I have

```
    <sslContext>         
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/cert/broker.ks" keyStorePassword="password"     trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/cert/client.ts" trustStorePassword="password"/>      
    </sslContext>
<transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://127.0.0.1:61617?needClientAuth=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

On starting the broker I am getting the message

```
INFO | Listening for connections at: ssl://127.0.0.1:61617?needClientAuth=true
 INFO | Connector ssl started
```

### So, my broker is ready to listen over ssl.

In other cmd I am starting my java spring project jar......and I am getting the following log :

```
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,146] [DEBUG] WireFormatNegotiator.negociate() - ssl://localhost/127.0.0.1:61617 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=9, cacheEnabled=tru
e, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,167] [DEBUG] TaskRunnerFactory.init() - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Session Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.Thre
adPoolExecutor@650e1899[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,169] [INFO ] WalletManager.run() -

########################## Wallet MANAGER UP ##########################
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,181] [DEBUG] CustomJmsTemplate.execute() - Executing callback on JMS Session: PooledSession { ActiveMQSession {id=ID:Psylocke-59003-140598047
8859-3:1:3,started=true} }
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,219] [DEBUG] CustomJmsTemplate.doSend() - Sending created message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId
= null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arriv
al = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0
, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@18f9a7a8, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure
= null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false}
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,229] [DEBUG] CustomJmsTemplate.execute() - Executing callback on JMS Session: PooledSession { ActiveMQSession {id=ID:Psylocke-59003-140598047
8859-1:1:2,started=true} }
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,260] [DEBUG] CustomJmsTemplate.doSend() - Sending created message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId
= null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arriv
al = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0
, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@ca2027f, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure =
 null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false}
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,312] [DEBUG] WalletManager.processUIMessage() - ### UI ### GetWalletPositions processing stared ### UI ###
[21 Jul 2014 15:07:59,313] [DEBUG] WalletManager.processUIMessage() - ### UI ### GetWalletPositions processing ended ### UI ###
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:19,036] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - WriteChecker 10001 ms elapsed since last write check.
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:19,038] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61617]
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:19,145] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - WriteChecker 10000 ms elapsed since last write check.
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:19,145] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61617]
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:29,036] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - WriteChecker 10000 ms elapsed since last write check.
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:29,036] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61617]
[21 Jul 2014 15:08:29,145] [DEBUG] AbstractInactivityMonitor.run() - WriteChecker 10000 ms elapsed since last write check.
```

### For authentication and authorization purpose I am using the below plugin in activemq.xml. I want only the "system" user to connect and no other guest user or incorrect username should access :

```
<plugins>
        <!-- Configure authentication; Username, passwords and groups -->
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="system" password="${activemq.password}" groups="users,admins"/>
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>


      <!--  Lets configure a destination based authorization mechanism -->
      <authorizationPlugin>
        <map>
          <authorizationMap>
            <authorizationEntries>
              <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
              <authorizationEntry queue="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users" />

              <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins" />
              <authorizationEntry topic="USERS.>" read="users" write="users" admin="users" />

              <!-- <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="guests,users" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users"/> -->
            </authorizationEntries>
          </authorizationMap>
        </map>
      </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

### In my spring context file for the WalletManager project i have

```
    <bean id="activeMQConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"   destroy-method="stop" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL">
                    <value>ssl://${activemq.zdchange.hostname}:${activemq.zdchange.port}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="keyStore" value="broker.ks"/>
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="keypass"/>
                <property name="trustStore" value="client.ts"/>
                <property name="trustStorePassword" value="keypass"/>
                 <property name="userName" value="system"/>
                <property name="password" value="manager"/> 
                <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
                <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/> 
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  JMS Connection Factory for walletcontroller -->
    <bean id="activeMQConnectionFactory_forSC" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL">

                    <value>ssl://${activemq.sc.hostname}:${activemq.sc.port}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="keyStore" value="broker.ks"/>
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="keypass"/>
                <property name="trustStore" value="client.ts"/>
                <property name="trustStorePassword" value="keypass"/>
                 <property name="userName" value="system"/>
                <property name="password" value="manager"/> 
                <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
                <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/> 
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now even if I am giving incorrect password for "system" or commenting the below lines

```
<property name="userName" value="system"/>
                    <property name="password" value="manager"/>
```

still it is getting connected to the broker. Is my authentication and authorization not done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed all the steps again today and it is working now. This is what I did.

Followed http://codebrane.com/blog/2012/07/13/activemq-ssl-exchanges-and-handshake-error-messages/   to create the certificates.
Set the broker environment.

---

The two files broker-keystore.ks and broker-truststore.ks are placed at apache-activemq-5.10.0\conf folder.

### Activemq configuration

```
<sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker-keystore.ks" keyStorePassword="password" 
                    trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker-truststore.ks" trustStorePassword="password"/>
    </sslContext>

    <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://localhost:61617?transport.needClientAuth=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

### Set the client environment

Placed the client keystore and truststore at the proper location
Used ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory

```
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL">
                    <value>ssl://localhost:61617</value>
                </property>
                <property name="keyStore" value="client-keystore.ks"/>
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password"/>
                <property name="trustStore" value="client-truststore.ks"/>
                <property name="trustStorePassword" value="password"/>
                <property name="userName" value="abc"/>
                <property name="password" value="pass"/>
                <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
                <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/> 
            </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible that you have your `activemq.xml` misconfigured? Did you check your log?